# Microsoft Edge WebDriver - Unexpected error. Unknown error

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-edgedriver

I am getting the following exception when trying to get Microsoft Edge automation to work with Selenium:

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: Unexpected error. Unknown error

I am using the *Selenium.WebDriver.MicrosoftDriver* NuGet package, version 17.17134.0.

My code is simply the constructor:

```
var driver = new EdgeDriver();
```

I have tried various overloads that are suggested:

```
var driver = new EdgeDriver(new EdgeOptions());

var driver = new EdgeDriver(pathToMicrosoftWebDriverExecutable);
```

No luck.  I made sure that the WebDriver version from Microsoft matched the Edge version on the machine running the tests.

Is there any way I can get a more informative error message here?  Note that all Selenium unit tests work as expected with both the Firefox and Chrome WebDrivers, it's only Edge that won't work.

Comment: any updates on the issue? I have same problem :/

Comment: @micnyk I was unable to resolve this issue and have had our Edge tests go stale due to it.  I have not taken the time to open a support case with Microsoft, which may be the best option here.  I'm surprised more people aren't having the same issue, I'm not sure why it is occurring for us.

Comment: Same issue here. I guess people just don't use Edge much, so not many devs bother to auto test in it...

Comment: I'm still having the same issue much later.  I tried installing developer mode as suggested below and it didn't resolve the issue either.  I'm still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I know you mentioned you had the same versions, but I was getting the same error myself and this is how I resolved it so hopefully this helps.

It appears that Microsoft is no longer releasing the Web Driver as a standalone version, which may be the issue. ([See here for more details](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2018/06/14/webdriver-w3c-recommendation-feature-on-demand/#H075kxeGl2cXqyeF.97)) Currently, Edge seems to be at version 17763, whereas the NuGet package is 17134. So what I had to do was go in and "install it as a standalone by going to Settings > Apps > Apps & features > Manage optional features." There are some alternative directions that are included in the link above.

Once that installed I pointed the driver to the location and it finally worked.

```
var driver = new EdgeDriver("C:\\Windows\\System32\\", edgeOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how or why, but this worked for me, also.  I was getting the pesky "Message: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Unexpected error. Unknown error".

I followed Brian Murphy's instructions to install Microsoft Edge Driver as a Standalone by managing my optional features.  I don't know where windows installed it, and I didn't need to change any of my code in C#, and my test which was previously failing at
Driver = new EdgeDriver(edgeService, options);

once again started to pass.

Comment: What did you do to initialize the edgeService?  Perhaps this is the key for yours working.  I tried not specifying the c:\windows\system32 location, but that didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

This answer doesn't necessarily solve all edge driver issues, but I was able to get past this error by downloading the specific edge driver matching the version of edge I have installed from here:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/

In my case, I am using "88.0.705.74" of Edge so I downloaded:

https://msedgedriver.azureedge.net/88.0.705.74/edgedriver_win64.zip

Once I downloaded the driver, I unzipped it locally, but when I specify the directory in C#, it expects the file name to be "MicrosoftWebDriver.exe" instead of "msedgedriver.exe", so I renamed it accordingly:

```
EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
IWebDriver edgeDriver = new EdgeDriver("C:\\Users\\[username]\\Downloads\\edgedriver_win64", options);
```

Now, it loads the driver, I just ran into a couple other errors depending on the machine and account I was running under.  I was able to get Edge to navigate to a page.

Comment: Update to this: If you download per MS's instructions you might have to use this syntax:


`_driver = new EdgeDriver(EdgeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"C:\bin\EdgeDriver", "msedgedriver.exe"), options);`