# Microsoft Edge WebDriver throws 'Unexpected error. Unknown error' when you try to initialize

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, microsoft-edge

I am getting the following exception when I try to initialize the webdriver instance for Microsoft EdgeDriver. I am using the MicrosoftDriver version - 16.16299.0

I have verified the version of OS and Edge on my machine and used the WebDriver version accordingly.

> OS Build : 16299.1087
>   
>   Microsoft Edge : 41.16299.1004.0
>   
>   Selenium.WebDriver.MicrosoftDriver : 16.16299.0

```
EdgeDriver edge = new EdgeDriver(path);
```

Below is the error message:

```
{"Unexpected error. Unknown error"}
Type: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException

Stack Trace:

   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Edge.EdgeDriver..ctor(String edgeDriverDirectory, EdgeOptions options)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Edge.EdgeDriver..ctor(String edgeDriverDirectory)
   at EdgeDriverTest.UnitTest1.TestMethod1()
```

I gave a try using the latest version of Edge WebDriver but no luck. Is there a way to get more informative message?

Comment: It seems you're using the older version of edge and webdriver. My suggestion is  installing the latest update and again try to make a test with the latest driver to check the result. You can also refer to [this issue](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/15558750/), it's like a similar issue.

Comment: This is also a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53540426/microsoft-edge-webdriver-unexpected-error-unknown-error).